# Compare two pairs of columns from one dataframe to detect mismatches and show the value from another column in the same row

Tags: r, dataframe

I´m trying to solve the following problem. I have a dataframe like the following:

```
 id <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
 ref <- c("A", "G", "C", "T")
 alt <- c("T", "C", "G", "A")
 ref1 <- c("A", "C", "T", "T")
 alt1 <- c("T", "G", "A", "A")
 df <- data.frame(id, ref,  alt, ref1, alt1)
```

I need to compare the values in ref/alt column pair and see if it matches to ref1/alt1 values for each row of the dataframe. If it doesn´t match I want that r return the id value for the same row.
I was having trouble to find a simple code to do that and I´ll appreciate a suggestion!

Thanks in advance

`dput()` output of `df`:

```
structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ref = c("A", "G", 
"C", "T"), alt = c("T", "C", "G", "A"), ref1 = c("A", "C", "T", 
"T"), alt1 = c("T", "G", "A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution.

```
libary(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(ref_check = ref == ref1,
         alt_check = alt == alt1,
         both_ceck = ref_check & alt_check) %>% 
  filter(!both_ceck) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

And a `base R` solution.

```
df[df$ref != df$ref1 & df$alt != df$alt1, ]$id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifelse as follow:

```
library(tidyverse)

matches <- df %>% 
   mutate(check = ifelse(alt==alt1 & ref==ref1, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
   filter(check=="Yes") 

unique(matches$id)
```

Comment: This works, but to fully answer the question you would want to filter for "No", not "Yes". At the same time the `ifelse()` part can be skipped. Whenever you do a comparison statement and that will return a `logical` (`TRUE`/`FALSE`), and that is usually more useful further down the line, than using a `character` variable. In this case it makes the `filter()` more simple. `df %>% mutate(check = alt == alt1 & ref == ref1) %>% filter(!check) %>% pull(id)` does the trick.